# pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('HY000', 'The SQL contains 0 parameter markers,

Tags: pyodbc, pypyodbc

There are connection with Oracle (works good):

```
import pypyodbc as pyodbc
cnxn=pyodbc.connect("DSN=ORCL;PWD=user1")
cursor=cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from t_v01")
s = 'sss'
f = 'fff'
cursor.execute("select * from t_v01 where t_id = ? ",[s,]) 
#works good (above)

cursor.execute("insert into t_v01 (t_id,t_type) values (?,?)",[(s,f,),] )
```

Give the mentioned error: `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('HY000', 'The SQL contains 0 parameter markers,..`

But in previous step Python saw the parameter marker "?". Why?